# Knockout dynamic server side data-binding two way handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Below knockout example is working fine for listing and refreshing itself after each second.

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="listing-grid">
        <div class="listing_wrapper">
            <!--Listing Columns-->
            <div class="column heading option_cols">
                Order Level
            </div>
            <div class="column heading desig_cols">
                Designation Name
            </div>
            <div class="column heading desig_cols">
                Job Description
            </div>
            <div class="column heading option_cols">
                Options
            </div>
            <!--Listing Data-->
        </div>
        <form name="desig_order_level" action="<?php echo $url?>manage/designation_order_level/" id="desig_order_level">
        <div class="listing_wrapper" data-bind="foreach: Designations">
            <div class="column data_display option_cols">
                <input name="orders[]" data-bind="value: Desig_Order" class="fancyInput_smaller">
            </div>
            <div class="column data_display desig_cols" data-bind="text: Desig_Name"></div>
            <div class="column data_display desig_cols" data-bind="text: Desig_Desc"></div>
            <div class="column data_display option_cols">
                Remove
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function GetDesignations(handleData) {
  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_designations.php',
        type: "post",
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            handleData(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert('Failed');
        }
    });
}

$(function () {

  var Designation_ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Designations = ko.observableArray();
    
    self.update = function() {
        
        GetDesignations(function(output){
            self.Designations.removeAll();
            $.each(output, function (i) {
                self.Designations.push(new deisgnation_data_binding(output[i]));
            });
        });
    };
    self.addnewItem = function () {
        var newitem = JSON.parse('{"Name":"'+$("#Name").val()+'", "Desig_desc":"'+$("#Desig_desc").val()+'"}');
        self.Designations.push(
            new deisgnation_data_binding(newitem)
        );
    };
    self.removeToDoItem = function(item) {
        self.Designations.remove(item);
    };
    
  };
  
var Designation_ViewModel = new Designation_ViewModel();
var y = window.setInterval(Designation_ViewModel.update,1000);
ko.applyBindings(Designation_ViewModel, document.getElementById("designations_items"));

});
var deisgnation_data_binding = function (data) {
    return {
        Desig_Order: ko.observable(data.Desig_Order),
        Desig_Name: ko.observable(data.Desig_Name),
        Desig_Desc: ko.observable(data.Desig_Desc)
    };
};
```

Issue # 1). that at user side, I cannot take input new values in order level input box to update order level, when I select the text box to enter new value all listing gets updated and refreshed. Due to this reason unable to let user update order level.

Issue # 2). that at user side, when I click Remove link, it simply removes item from observable array while I need to parse have an ID to set on Remove link for each record listed so that when remove button is clicked it gives some identical ID to remove method where we can run a server side Ajax call to remove item from database also.

Any logical interface for these two matters to manage in knockout listing, please?

Comment: Issue # 1). Since you are calling GetDesignations every 1 sec, data will be updated to values from server. What is that you are expecting? Please create a jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: I want system let users input value to update form... right now it is not happening because whenever user try to input value, listing get refreshed and all new values get wiped out with listed one.

Comment: You have written the code to update the form every second. If you remove setInterval call and make a normal call to that method, you will be able to enter the values. var y = window.setInterval(Designation_ViewModel.update,1000);. But i think you have a requirement to refresh every second with values from DB?